# Search results not showing in dashboard

Tags: magento, search-engine

When my customers search in my searchbox (which uses form.mini.phtml), there results won't show up in my dashboard (Magento 1.7).

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $catalogSearchHelper =  $this->helper('catalogsearch');
?>
<div class="search-form">
    <form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('search/result') ?>" method="get">
        <input id="search" type="text" name="query" value="" maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>" />
        <button><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('Search Products and Pages...') ?>');
    </script>
</div>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced'); ?>"><i><?php echo $this->__('Advanced Search'); ?></i></a>
```

The results won't show up in my Dashboard, and in the search terms menu under 'Catalog'.

Where should this save action take place?

If i manually add a search term under Catalog -> Search terms, it does show up at 'Latest 5 search terms'.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the setting for popular search terms is enabled under

> /admin/system_config/edit/section/catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations
>   and flush your cache.

Comment: The setting is enabled, i have flushed my cache to be sure, no difference.

Comment: After doing a search check to see if the term is added to catalogsearch_query. If it isn't check your apache error logs and magento root/var/log/exception.log and system.log to see if anything is ouput. Attempt to disable cache and re-test.

Comment: The term is not added, and there is no attempt in the log, i tried disabling all the caches, it makes no difference.